# Combinations and Probability with Cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I don't really understand the following problem, so if someone could set up the process for me it would be appreciated.

Suppose that I draw two cards out of a set of $52$. If I know that these $2$ cards are both spades, how many different hands would there be?
I know that there are $13$ spades in a set of cards, but would the order matter?

Answer (score 3):

Order would not matter. If you drew a 10 of Spades, then a Jack of Spades, would you differentiate that from drawing the Jack first followed by the 10? I personally wouldn't. So since order doesn't matter, there are $\binom{13}{2}$ such hands.